# How can pipe producer tell pipe consumer it has reached 'End of File'?" (un-named-pipe, not named-pipe)

Tags: pipe, here-document, here-string

I have an application which requires a *producer* to send filenames to a *consumer*, and have *producer* indicate to the *consumer* when the last filename has been sent and the *end of file* has been reached.

For simplicity, in the following example *producer*  is demonstrated with `echo` and `printf`, while the consumer is demonstrated with `cat`.  I have tried to extrapolate the "here file" method without success, using `<<EOF` to indicate to the *producer-wrapper* (if such a thing exists) what to look for as an indication of *end of file*.  If it worked `cat` should filter `EOF` from the output.

Ex 1)

**input**

```
{
echo "Hello World!" 
printf '\x04' 
echo "EOF"
} <<EOF |\
cat
```

**output**

```
bash: warning: here-document at line 146 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
Hello World!
EOF
```

Ex 2)

**input**

```
{ 
echo "Hello World!" 
printf '\x04' 
echo "EOF"
} |\
cat <<EOF
```

**output**

```
bash: warning: here-document at line 153 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

**Is it correct that the "here files" method for indicating delimiter only works for static text, and not dynamically created text?**

**-- the actual application --**

```
inotifywait -m --format '%w%f' /Dir |  <consumer>
```

The consumer is waiting for files to be written to directory /Dir.
It would be nice if when a file "/Dir/EOF" was written the consumer would detect logical end-of-file condition simply by writing shell script as follows:

```
inotifywait -m --format '%w%f' /Dir |<</Dir/EOF  <consumer>
```

**-- In response to Giles answer --**

Is it theoretically possible to implement

```
cat <<EOF
hello
world
EOF
```

as

```
SpecialSymbol="EOF"
{
    echo hello
    echo world
    echo $SpecialSymbol
} |\
while read Line; do 
  if [[ $Line == $SpecialSymbol ]]
    break
  else 
    echo $Line
  fi
done |\
cat
```

By theoretically possible I mean *"would it support existing usage patterns and only enable extra usage patterns which had previously been illegal syntax?"* - meaning no existing legal code would be broken.

Comment: Why not have the sender close the pipe after it is done sending files?

Comment: @CraigHicks: shell statements in 'round brackets' (US parentheses) run in a subshell but do not by themselves involve any kind of pipes. You may be thinking of process substitution using 'angle' characters _and_ parentheses `>( command )` and `<( command )`which in some implementations sometimes use pipes, but if those pipes do have names using the name would only allow you to _open_ them redundantly NOT close them.

Comment: You don't need escape newline after `|`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a pipe, the end of file is seen by the consumer(s) once all the producers have closed their file descriptor to the pipe and the consumer has read all the data.

So, in:

```
{
  echo foo
  echo bar
} | cat
```

`cat` will see end-of-file as soon as the second `echo` terminates and `cat` has read both `foo\n` and `bar\n`. There's nothing more for you to do.

Things to bear in mind though is that if some of the commands on the left side of the pipe starts some background process, that background process will inherit a fd to the pipe (its stdout), so `cat` will not see eof until that process also dies or closes its stdout. As in:

```
{
  echo foo
  sleep 10 &
  echo bar
} | cat
```

You see `cat` not returning before 10 seconds have passed.

Here, you may want to redirect `sleep`'s stdout to  something else like `/dev/null` if you don't want its (non)output to be fed to `cat`:

```
{
  echo foo
  sleep 10 > /dev/null &
  echo bar
} | cat
```

If you want the writing end of the pipe to be closed before the last command in the subshell left of the `|` is run, you can close stdout or redirecting to that subshell in the middle of the subshell with `exec`, like:

```
{
  echo foo
  exec > /dev/null
  sleep 10
} | (cat; echo "cat is now gone")
```

However note that most shells will still wait for that subshell in addition to the `cat` command. So while you'll see `cat is now gone` straight away (after `foo` is read), you'll still have to wait 10 seconds for the whole pipeline to finish. Of course, in that example above, it would make more sense to write it:

```
echo foo | cat
sleep 10
```

`<<ANYTHING...content...ANYTHING` is a here-document, it's to make the stdin of command a file that contains the *content*. It wouldn't be useful there. `\4` is byte that when read from a terminal makes data held by a terminal device be flushed to the application reading from it (and when there's no data, `read()` returns 0 which means end-of-file). Again, not of any use here.

Comment: - It answers exactly how the un-named pipe is closed in two way: (1) the normal way e.g. ending the process of the pipe writer (2) using the trick of "exec >/dev/null".  Therefore I select this as the answer.

Comment: I have modified my question to make it clearer what I was trying to achieve by suggesting a new and backwards-compat  use for "<< <special symbol>".

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your attempt is that what you call “the here-file method” simply doesn't exist. Here documents are a feature of the syntax of the shell programming language. They don't get interpreted by applications such as `cat`.

Consider a shell script with a here document:

```
cat <<EOF
hello
world
EOF
```

The way it works is that as part of parsing the script, the shell interpreter sees the here document syntactic construct. When it runs these lines of code, the interpreter gathers the data and passes it as input to `cat`. Depending on the shell, this is essentially equivalent to either

```
echo 'hello
world
' >/tmp/heredoc.tmp
cat </tmp/heredoc.tmp
rm /tmp/heredoc.tmp
```

(but with saner management of the temporary file) or to

```
echo 'hello
world
' | cat
```

If you have `echo EOF` and you want this to indicate the end of a here document, then the output of the `echo` command must be a shell.

```
{
  echo 'cat <<EOF'
  echo hello
  echo world
  echo EOF
} | sh
```

This works but it's rarely useful.

None of this helps you to do what you set out to do. There's nothing magical about a here document that makes it end “harder” than any other input. End-of-file is not a marker that gets transmitted over the input channel, it's a condition of the input channel. When the input is a regular file, the end-of-file condition is triggered when the application tries to read past the last byte of the file. When the input is a pipe (named or not), the end-of-file condition is triggered when the application tries to read but the producer has closed the pipe.

Usually it's enough to write

```
producer | consumer
```

When `producer` exits, the write end of the pipe will be closed since no process has it open any longer. If you want the pipe to be closed earlier, arrange for the producer to close its standard output (`exec >&-` in sh, `close(1)` in C).

Note that to reach end-of-file on a pipe, all the processes that had the write end of the pipe open must have closed it. If the producer runs background processes, you may want to set the close-on-exec flag on the pipe (`fcntl(1, F_SETFD, fcntl(1, F_GETFC, 0) | FD_CLOEXEC)`) before forking them.

Comment: Terrific answer and you include the stdout switch "exec >&-".  Steph also had the output redirect in his answer and it was an earlier response , so I selected that as the answer.  No hard feelings I hope.

Apart from that, I have modified my question in response to your answer about underlying implementation - I would be grateful if you have time to read it.

Comment: @CraigHicks Regarding your addition: that doesn't make sense. You've written a program that prints `hello` `world` in a very complicated way, why would you want to do this?

Comment: if you look at my modified question in the new section "-- the actual application --" you will see that it is not about another way to write "hello world", but about a way to pass locally-specified special text symbols as a method to close pipes.  The explicit example uses "inotifywait"

Comment: @CraigHicks If you want to wait for one event with `inotifywait`, don't pass the `-m` flag! And once again, **you do not close a pipe by sending data to it**. You close a pipe… by closing the pipe!

Comment: If you don't specify the -m flag, then inotifywait will return at the first event.  If  inotifywait is called in a loop, then between returning from one wait and entering the next, events could be missed.   (Unless of course inotify doesn't stop waiting for events, but there is nothing in the documentation for the version of inotifywait I am using (Ubuntu 16.04.3) that that is the case.  (And if it were how would the waiting stop?  No handle is returned from inotifywait).

Comment: @CraigHicks If you're monitoring events, then the consumer must trigger for each event, not on end-of-file.

Comment: Following the flow of your reply, you used possible psuedo-code  implementations of here-file syntax to demonstrate here-file semantics.  In my answer to you I demonstrate another possible psuedo-code  implementation of here-file syntax could both satisfy existing semantics and enable new symatics for closing un-named pipes in a shell file - the "inotifywait -m" example demonstrates  one convenient usage example.  I am not saying it "should" be done, only that it "could" be done.  Truly I soon can't think of many other examples where it would be handy - but that is not the point.

Comment: "If you're monitoring events, then the consumer must trigger for each event, not on end-of-file" -- "inotifywait -m" does exactly that and echos the filename.  That echoed filename is then available in real time to <consumer>

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a FIFO then you can do so, of course:

**script 1**

```
FIFO_PATH="/path/to/fifo"
exec 3<"$FIFO_PATH" # stalls until FIFO is opened for writing, too
while read line; do
    : whatever
done <&3
exec 3<&-
: continue script
```

**script 2**

```
FIFO_PATH="/path/to/fifo"
exec 3>"$FIFO_PATH" # stalls until FIFO is opened for reading, too
echo foo >&4
exec 4>&-
: continue script
```

Comment: Very compact.  Thanks for taking the time to explain about named pipes.

Comment: I have modified my question to make it clearer what I was trying to achieve by suggesting a new and backwards-compat use for "<< <special symbol>".